# Complex analysis - Trigonometric conjugate

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I'm having trouble with this assignment:

Show that $ \overline {\cos(z)} = \cos(\bar z)$, where $\bar z$ represents conjugate of $z$.

I know that the two are equal, but how to mathematically show it?

Comment: Try to prove something more general: If $f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$ and $f$ takes real values on the real axis, then $\overline{f(z)} = f(\overline{z})$ for all $z$. Or look at the power series expansion of $\cos$.

Comment: Can always also use $\cos z = (e^{iz}+e^{-iz})/2$ though that is much less fun.

Comment: First, you need a definition of $\cos z$ for complex $z$.  Then use that definition in your proof.  Since we do not know which definition was in your text, we can only guess at what answer you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use [Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) to show that $\cos(ix)= \cosh(x)$ and $\sin(ix)= i\sinh(x)$
$$\begin{align*}
\overline{\cos(x + iy)} &= \overline{ \cos(x) \cos(iy) - \sin(x)\sin(iy)}\\ 
 &= \overline{\cos(x)\cosh(y)- i \sin(x)\sinh(y)}\\ 
 &= \cos(x)\cosh(y)+ i \sin(x)\sinh(y)\\ 
 &=  \cos(x)\cos(iy)+ \sin(x)\sin(iy)\\ 
 &= \cos(x - iy) \\
 &= \cos( \overline{x+iy})
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 3):

Well i do it this way:

\begin{align*}
\overline{\cos(z)} &=  \frac {\overline {e^{iz} + e^{-iz}}}{\overline{2}} \\
                   &=  \frac {\overline {e^{iz}} + \overline {e^{-iz}}}{2} \\
                   &=  \frac {e^\overline{iz} + e^\overline{-iz}}{2} \\
                   &=  \frac {e^{-i\overline{z}} + e^{i\overline{z}}}{2} \\
                   &=  \frac {e^{i\overline{z}} + e^{-i\overline{z}}}{2} \\
                   &= cos(\overline{z})
\end{align*}